# How can I convert a ventless propane fireplace to natural gas?

Tags: fireplace, natural-gas, propane

I just bought a property and it has a passthrough, ventless fireplace that runs on propane.

I've not hooked up propane to the house, and the natural gas company says they'll hook me up for free. However, the fireplace is currently configured to run off of propane.

I tired to call the manufacturer, but they wont talk to me and told me to call a dealership, which I did. They say it's impossible, and I'll have to buy a new log set, and since it's a double sided log set, they start at a price that's way above my budget.

However, all the log sets they sell can come configured as either propane or natural gas, and my research indicates that all I have to do to convert it is to replace the regulator and the orifices with ones designed for natural gas.

Is my research correct, or is the dealer correct?

This log set has been discontinued recently (it's less than six years old), where can I find the parts I need, and which parts do I need?

Comment: Many gas appliances can run on either natural gas or propane, as you've discovered, but maybe the dealer is telling you that they don't make or carry the right regulator for your model? I would try the manufacturer again; perhaps the dealer is just trying to upsell you. In any event, I would not jerry-rig a regulator from a different fireplace unless you get a professional to OK it.

Comment: I found an online dealership selling parts for the fireplace, and it looks like the fireplace has a separate set of parts for natural gas, and propane. I just need to figure out which parts to buy.

Comment: Well that sounds promising: you know that 1) your model was available for natural gas, and 2) there's a dealership that still stocks parts for it. Why don't you email them directly and ask them?

Comment: As you are using an unvented gas appliance I would invest in a carbon monoxide detector.

Comment: I have a carbon monoxide detector

Comment: Yes you are correct all you should need to do is new size injectors and install a reg to suit the appliance/pressure. Having said that I'm not up to date on flueless gas wood heaters as they are illegal in Aus

Comment: You might ask your gas company.   They may be able to refer you to someone, or possibly do the conversion themselves.

Comment: You don't want to convert, let alone probably even use, a ventless fireplace.

Comment: But to answer your question, from what I understand, the difference between propane and gas fixtures is mostly the burner itself...namely the size of the openings to regulate the fuel flow.

Comment: You need to post vendor & model to have a hope of an answer to 'which parts do I need'?  A photo would help a lot also, in terms of advice.

Comment: I have changed stove & ovens, fireplaces in the past and even bbq grills in the past and the only difference was the change in the orifice after the gas regulator on all of these, I would look into that. I missed the ventless part and would never even use a ventless model legal or illegal, just my opinion but I had a co worker and her 2 dogs die of co poisoning a few years back.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is all you need is a new orifice.

The complicated answer is : don't do that.  Ventless systems have been banned in various places, and come with significant hazards not fully mitigated by a carbon monoxide detector.  Read for instance : http://www.energyvanguard.com/blog-building-science-HERS-BPI/bid/48762/Bob-Vila-and-the-Vent-Free-Gas-Fireplace-A-Sorry-State-of-Affairs

A choice quote: *"After doing research, we decided we would never put a vent-free (room vented) appliance into our home. Because of this decision, we didn't believe it would be right to sell them to our customers."*

I would suggest asking a different question "how can I vent this ventless gas log set?".  You could also calculate the number of heating days : if this is just decoration perhaps it's cheaper to just run it on propane until it dies.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on the same topic.  Basically I was told that physically it can be done, but it is highly illegal.  Something to do with the factory labeling on the fireplace would then be inaccurate.  As for me, lacking the technical information I need to convert and the fact this fireplace will emit co2, I'm going to follow the safer path.

Comment: CO2 (carbon dioxide) is not a problem:  animals and plants produce it.  CO (carbon monoxide) is toxic, but a properly operating gas burner does not emit dangerous quantities.   Ventless fireplaces *are* legal in some jurisdictions, but yes, Canada and Australia have banned them.

Answer (score 0):

Charmglow branded stoves and fireplaces are fixed to only be able to use the fuel set at the factory. You could probably take the regulator assembly in to a shop that could fit it for a change with a different orifice, but you best check local codes to make sure it's then tagged appropriately for the change. Some newer Gas Stoves and Appliances are switchable on the appliance. Which indicates which fuel is being used by them! ....then you simply use whichever fuel it's switched for.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I've remove a lot of irrelevant material from your answer; please only include what actually answers the original question.

Comment: @Daniel Griscom  Well I guess my 30+ yrs experience in gas hook ups is not needed here. So I'll not bother commenting on Stack Exchange so you can furnish all the answers and not have to edit most of my comments out anyway! Thanks.... for nothing! Bye! :D